# How to eat keys in WM_KEYDOWN

Tags: c, winapi

Im handling the `WM_KEYDOWN` message in an edit box.
I am handling a bunch of keys, but for certain keys (eg. tab) i'd like to prevent the displayable character from being appended to the editbox.

```
case WM_KEYDOWN:
    {
        switch(wParam)
        {
        case VK_TAB:
            //handle tab here
            //Eat tab key
            return 0;
        default:
            return DefWndProc(hwnd,message,wParam,lParam);
        }
     }
     break;
```

I can detect and delete the tab in `WM_KEYUP` message, but with this method the tab key is visibly added and removed from the edit box.

is there any way of eating a key in `WM_KEYDOWN`?

Comment: Have you tried handling `WM_CHAR` instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Override [`PreTranslateMessage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/kkbhxcs2%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) in your dialog class.
2. If the [`MSG`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/900ks98t%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) parameter's `message` is `WM_KEYDOWN` and the `wParam` is `VK_TAB` and the `hwnd` is that of your edit control, handle it and simply return TRUE.

Returning TRUE means that that event has already been processed and thus will not be processed by the `CEdit` control.

Answer (score 5):

The intended way for you to do this is to handle the [`WM_GETDLGCODE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645425.aspx) message and tell the Window manager that the edit control does not want to handle the <kbd>TAB</kbd> key. Raymond Chen covers this very issue in this article: [Those who do not understand the dialog manager are doomed to reimplement it, badly](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2007/06/27/3555596.aspx). As often the case with Raymond, quite a provocative title to the article.

The code sample from the article looks like this:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK SubclassWndProc(
    HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
  LRESULT lres;
  switch (uMsg) {
  case WM_GETDLGCODE:
    lres = CallWindowProc(...);
    lres &= ~DLGC_WANTTAB;
    if (lParam &&
        ((MSG *)lParam)->message == WM_KEYDOWN &&
        ((MSG *)lParam)->wParam == VK_TAB) {
      lres &= ~DLGC_WANTMESSAGE;
    }
    return lres;
  }
  return CallWindowProc(...);
}
```

Comment: I had no idea about this! So is my answer wrong? (even though it gets the job done)

Comment: @AnishRam I would not say that your answer is wrong. And I'm not an expert on the dialog manager. And it's still a little unclear on the exact design and architecture of the app in question. However, I would say that if a `WM_GETDLGCODE` based approach solves the problem then it is very very likely that the `WM_GETDLGCODE` based approach is the best solution.

Comment: It certainly seems that way. Thank you for your answer :)

Comment: @AnishRamaswamy your method is better for keys other than VK_TAB.

Comment: @MarkRansom, How so?

Answer (score 0):

Capture event and pass messages by yourself.

a WinApi Tutorial should help You, how to modify the message queue by Yourself, resp. send own messages, or preventing sending them.

http://www.winprog.org/tutorial/message_loop.html