# Multiline EDIT dialog control doesn't take tabs despite DLGC_WANTTAB

Tags: c, windows, winapi, input

I want a multiline `EDIT` control, which is a child of a dialog, to take tabs as regular text input (instead of switching to the next control).

According to multiple resources, the correct way of doing this is to handle `WM_GETDLGCODE` and returning `DLGC_WANTTAB` (or checking + `DLGC_WANTMESSAGE`).

See:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/16668256/653473
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/42352363/653473
- Raymond Chen's first comment here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18444839/653473

[Raymond's article](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20070627-00/?p=26243) suggests that what I want is in fact the default behavior, which is not what I'm observing.

**Reproduction:**

This is based on Visual Studio's default *Windows Desktop Application* C++ template. If you don't have that for some reason, the contents aren't that important; what's important is that there is an "About" dialog box being shown with the `DialogBox` function.

Create an EDIT control in the dialog, and subclass that:

```
WNDPROC OriginalEditWndProc;

// Message handler for about box.
INT_PTR CALLBACK About(HWND hDlg, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (message)
    {
        case WM_INITDIALOG:
        {
            HWND hEdit = CreateWindowExW(0, L"EDIT", NULL, WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | ES_MULTILINE, 0, 0, 100, 100, hDlg, NULL, NULL, NULL);
            OriginalEditWndProc = (WNDPROC)GetWindowLongPtrW(hEdit, GWLP_WNDPROC);
            SetWindowLongPtrW(hEdit, GWLP_WNDPROC, (LONG_PTR)EditSubclassProc);
            return (INT_PTR)TRUE;
        }
    }

    return (INT_PTR)FALSE;
}
```

Using this subclass `WNDPROC`:

```
static LRESULT CALLBACK EditSubclassProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    if (message == WM_GETDLGCODE)
    {
        OutputDebugStringA("WM_GETDLGCODE\r\n");
        return OriginalEditWndProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam) | DLGC_WANTTAB /* this should make it work */;
    }
    else if (message == WM_KEYDOWN)
    {
        if (wParam == VK_TAB)
        {
            OutputDebugStringA("got VK_TAB\r\n");
            return OriginalEditWndProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
        }
    }

    return OriginalEditWndProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
}
```

(Note that it makes no difference to use comctl32's `SetWindowSubclass`. Note also that this dialog is not functional because it does not handle a `WM_COMMAND` to be able close it, but that's irrelevant.)

**Observations:**

- We do get "got VK_TAB" every time tab is pressed.
- If `ES_MULTILINE` is present, then the keyboard focus goes to the OK button of the About dialog.
- If `ES_MULTILINE` is removed, then nothing happens upon pressing tab.
- Returning `DLGC_WANTMESSAGE` instead of merely `DLGC_WANTTAB` doesn't change anything.

Furthermore: If the About dialog is *not* displayed as a dialog (in other words, `IsDialogMessage` is not called), but as a regular window, then the behavior is different.

Change the way the dialog box is shown by modifying `IDM_ABOUT` handler:

```
case IDM_ABOUT:
{
    //DialogBox(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_ABOUTBOX), hWnd, About);
    HWND hDlg = CreateDialogParamW(NULL, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_ABOUTBOX), hWnd, About, 0);
    ShowWindow(hDlg, SW_SHOW);
    break;
}
```

**Observations:**

- There is one `WM_GETDLGCODE` when the dialog is first displayed (for reasons unknown), and then no more of these messages (as expected).
- We do get "got VK_TAB" every time tab is pressed.
- If `ES_MULTILINE` is present, a tab is inserted into the text (desired behavior).
- If `ES_MULTILINE` is removed, then nothing happens upon pressing tab (same as before).
- Returning `DLGC_WANTMESSAGE` instead of merely `DLGC_WANTTAB` doesn't change anything.

Firstly, these observations clash with [Raymond's article](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20070627-00/?p=26243). As written before, that article suggests that I should get tab characters inserted into the text by default, without doing anything. That's not what happens.

Secondly, `WM_GETDLGCODE` does in fact work as advertised, we do get `WM_KEYDOWN` with `VK_TAB`. I painfully debugged through the disassembly, and found out that:

- There are 2 different `WNDPROC` in the `EDIT` control, one for single line and one for multiline.
- Upon receiving the `WM_KEYDOWN` with `VK_TAB`, the multiline version (`MLWndProc` iirc) eventually calls `MLKeyDown`. That function then sends a `WM_NEXTDLGCTL` message. This is the culprit:

```
...
765D6DEA  push        ebx  
765D6DEB  push        0Dh  
765D6DED  push        100h  
765D6DF2  push        esi  
765D6DF3  jmp         MLKeyDown+1B6h (765D6D4Bh)  
765D6DF8  cmp         edx,1  
765D6DFB  jne         MLKeyDown+270h (765D6E05h)  
765D6DFD  push        ecx  
765D6DFE  push        9  
765D6E00  jmp         MLKeyDown+3C0h (765D6F55h)  
765D6E05  test        dword ptr [edi+68h],40000h  
765D6E0C  je          MLKeyDown+648h (765D71DDh)  
765D6E12  xor         eax,eax  
765D6E14  cmp         edx,2  
765D6E17  push        0  
765D6E19  sete        al  
765D6E1C  push        eax  
765D6E1D  push        28h  ; WM_NEXTDLGCTL
765D6E1F  push        dword ptr [edi+58h]  
765D6E22  call        SendMessageW (7658BB20h)
```

So it seems that the `EDIT` control insists on this behavior.

Something is not right here though. I cannot possibly be the first person to have that problem, and, again, Raymond's article suggests that this should not be happening in the first place.

Lastly:

Using v6 of the Common Controls library (which is used to get a "modern" visual style [for very modest definitions of "modern"]) doesn't change anything:

```
#pragma comment(linker,"\"/manifestdependency:type='win32' name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' processorArchitecture='*' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*'\"")
```

[Here is a repository with the entire project](https://github.com/HMd38kvVVlMQEfcb/DLG-EDIT-TEST)

Comment: are your edit have `WS_TABSTOP` style ?

Comment: @RbMm No. And adding it doesn't make any difference in any of the 4 possible combinations I've described. Iirc that flag only decides whether the dialog manager will give focus *to* a control.

Comment: in my test multi-line edit got focus with `WS_TABSTOP` style when pressing *TAB* and not got without this style.

Comment: @RbMm That makes sense and is probably correct, but is unrelated to the question.

Comment: edit control got `VK_TAB` in any case

Comment: your error that you call `OriginalEditWndProc` on `WM_GETDLGCODE` - dont do this ! simply return `DLGC_WANTCHARS|DLGC_HASSETSEL|DLGC_WANTALLKEYS|DLGC_WANTARROWS`

Comment: *That function then sends a WM_NEXTDLGCTL message.* - only in case `test        dword ptr [edi+68h],40000h` view that `40000` is set. and this flag is set during processing `WM_GETDLGCODE` - simply need not pass `WM_GETDLGCODE` to original procedure

Comment: @RbMm That appears to make it work. However, how can I verify that not passing a message (which would normally be passed) doesn't have unwanted side effects? I can't find any information on this.

Comment: *how can I verify* - no way. if you want documentation for this - you not found. you can do this or not do. and what *unwanted side effects* you wait ? if edit not inside dialog - it usually never got `WM_GETDLGCODE` at all. and so what ? look for notepad for example. i not view *unwanted side effects* here

Comment: @RbMm Agreed, you're probably right. Still, the documentation on this seems pretty lackluster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want that multi-line edit control process `VK_TAB` as if it is not inside a dialog - need not pass `WM_GETDLGCODE` to edit control, but process it by self. so solution can be next -

on `WM_INITDIALOG` call

```
SetWindowSubclass(GetDlgItem(hwndDlg, IDC_EDIT1), sSubclassProc, 0, 0);
```

(of course in place `IDC_EDIT1` your actual edit id)

and `sSubclassProc` can be very simply:

```
static LRESULT CALLBACK sSubclassProc(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam,
    LPARAM lParam, UINT_PTR uIdSubclass, DWORD_PTR /*dwRefData*/)
{
    switch (uMsg)
    {
    case WM_GETDLGCODE:
        return DLGC_WANTCHARS|DLGC_HASSETSEL|DLGC_WANTALLKEYS|DLGC_WANTARROWS;
    case WM_NCDESTROY:
        RemoveWindowSubclass(hWnd, sSubclassProc, uIdSubclass);
        break;
    }

    return DefSubclassProc(hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}
```

after this edit process `VK_TAB` key.

---

really it got `VK_TAB` (inside `WM_KEYDOWN` and `WM_CHAR`) in any case. but how process this - depend from some internal flag. it can insert tab-stop positions xor send `WM_NEXTDLGCTL` message to parent. this flag (you view it in assembly code - this is `test dword ptr [edi+68h],40000h` line is set during handle `WM_GETDLGCODE` message (dialog send this message to controls when process `WM_ACTIVATE`)

so your error was in line

```
return OriginalEditWndProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam) | DLGC_WANTTAB ;
```

you call `OriginalEditWndProc` and it set flag (40000 in [this+68h])

Comment: I'm going to accept this as I've successfully verified and tested it, although as I wrote in my other comment I'm reluctant to omit calling the original WNDPROC because I don't know what side effects that has. [This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/using-window-procedures#subclassing-a-window) confirms what you're saying (i.e. doesn't call the original WNDPROC), but in Raymond's article he *does* call the original WNDPROC, and then masks the unwanted bit from the return value.

Comment: @dialer - we don't have to always call the original procedure. we may or may not call it. and not everything can be documented. if you want to change the default behavior - you are already entering the undocumented area. and then your actions should first of all be based on your understanding of how it works

Comment: By the way, [according to this](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20070626-00/?p=26263), returning only `DLGC_WANTMESSAGE` would be appropriate here (and is, in fact, equivalent to your code because you include `DLGC_WANTALLKEYS`).

Comment: @dialer - yes, possible return `DLGC_WANTALLKEYS (== DLGC_WANTMESSAGE)` and so what ? sense not in this but in not call original edit procedure